# add a lambda and a number

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to accumulate a sum using lambda. so this is my program:

```
int maxDistance;
maxDistance += [&](){
        auto it = itStr1->begin()+5;
        string pNum{};
        while(*it != ']')
        {
            pNum += *it;
            it++;
        }
        return stoi(pNum);
        };
```

so naturally, my lambda returns an integer but I got a problem saying :

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and '(lambda at /lsp-17ba31a0-ec96-11eb-be58-cbc5eb4a2b22))
```

how to solve that ?

thank you

Comment: I think `maxDistance` is an int. You are trying to add to it a lambda not the output of the lambda . You have to call the lambda, then it will work

Comment: You don't *call* the lambda: `[&](){ ... }()` Note the trailing parentheses.

Comment: yes, my lambda returns an int too?

Comment: You don't call your lambda. Why would it return anything?

Comment: Note the difference between *returns* and *is* (lambda is not an int)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a lambda itself to an integer, but you can add *the result* of a lambda, if it *returns* an integer (like any other function). That means you have to actually *call* the lambda, which your example is not doing.

Try this instead:

```cpp
int maxDistance = 0;
maxDistance += [&](){
        auto it = itStr1->begin()+5;
        string pNum{};
        while(*it != ']')
        {
            pNum += *it;
            it++;
        }
        return stoi(pNum);
    }(); // <-- notice the () function call here!
```

Which is effectively equivalent to doing this:

```cpp
int maxDistance = 0;
auto lambda = [&](){
        auto it = itStr1->begin()+5;
        string pNum{};
        while(*it != ']')
        {
            pNum += *it;
            it++;
        }
        return stoi(pNum);
    };
maxDistance += lambda(); // <-- notice the () function call here!
```